# Custom formatting visuals based on legend

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

**I want to order my visuals by the legend in Power BI.**

I've a column in multiple tables of my data in Power BI, called `Severity`. The values are as follows: Critical, High, Medium, Low, Informational; **I would like my visuals to be in this order exactly.**

So far I've created a separate table in my data called `tblSeverityOrder` it lists the severities Critical, High, Medium, Low, informational with the values 1,2,3,4,5, respectively. I have then merged the queries so the numbers appear in the main data tables. I have then order my main data tables by the numbers (ascending).

Unfortunately, this does not have the desired affect as the severity is the "Legend" column in my report view. This is shown in the image below (**Notice:** High, Low, Medium) - The legend is not in the order I want it. Is there a way to do this?
[image]

**EDIT TO SHOW MORE INFO**

Order Table:

[image]

Relationship:

[image]

Visual:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you have create separate separate table with indexing. Its better to be a number.

[image]

Here your status should be High, Medium etc ...You can create it from here.  |

[image]

Then create relationship between severity and new table status column from data model.

[image]

Then you can select indexing table for order chart, I successfully added this for bar graph.

If you added successfully you will see 2 fields select when pie chart click.

[image]

Comment: A few things:
1. Indexing column for me just adds an ID field.
2. Can I add the relationship by specifying a link between tables?
3. Even when I add the link and choose status from my new sort table it doesn't order in the the order I have stated.

Comment: you can just create excel/csv and upload to power bi desktop.

Comment: I have the table, I have created the table

Comment: for 2nd question, yes, just drag and drop the column in to other column that needs to made relationship.

Comment: The issue I have is, it always sorts by a count of the findings rather than the order in my index table

Comment: did you try to order by index in visualization ?

Comment: Where is the order by? I am using sort by clicking the three dots on the visual.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad. just add status column to legend tab in visualization fields.

Comment: Not there, I am going to update my orginal question to show you my data fields and the setting on my visual

Comment: okay, sure. I will try to create pbix file for that.